# Misunderstanding the use of filter_extreme in gensim

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim

```
import gensim
corpus = [["a","b","c"],["a","d","e"],["a","f","g"]]
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
dct = Dictionary(corpus)
print(dct)
dct.filter_extremes(no_below=1)
print(dct)
```

When I ran the code above, my output was -

```
Dictionary(7 unique tokens: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']...)
Dictionary(6 unique tokens: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']...)
```

I supposed that since 'a' occurs in two documents, it should not be removed. However, this is not the case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation of `filter_extremes`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_extremes):

```
filter_extremes(no_below=5, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000, keep_tokens=None)

Notes:    
This removes all tokens in the dictionary that are:

    1. Less frequent than no_below documents (absolute number, e.g. 5) or
    2. More frequent than no_above documents (fraction of the total corpus size, e.g. 0.3).
    3. After (1) and (2), keep only the first keep_n most frequent tokens (or keep all if keep_n=None).
```

You are only passing `no_below=1`. This means that tokens appearing in less than 1 document (out of 3) are removed. This means `a` stays, as well as any other token in your corpus.

But then `no_above=0.5` is checked according to its default value, since you didn't pass an explicit value for this keyword. This means that tokens appearing in more than 50% of documents (out of 3, i.e. the ones appearing in at least 2) will be removed. And `'a'` appears in all 3 documents, it's the only one that appears in at least 2 documents as a matter of fact. This is why this token and this token alone is removed from the result. (The default 10000 value for `keep_n` implies that step 3 is a no-op in your example case.)

If you *only* want to strip low-frequency extremal tokens, pass an explicit `no_above=1.0` to `filter_extremes`.

Comment: Oh goodness! Thank you! I cannot believe I was making that mistake. 
Really appreciate it!

Comment: @dbloo no problem :)